# History of the previous routes

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an application developed in ionic. I have a screen that takes me to another, and this one in turn to another, and this can reach infinity.

I need to put a back button, how can I control all the steps I have back?

I have used `<ion-back-button> </ion-back-button>`.

History is supposed to be able to go back, but it doesn't do it correctly.

What solution or alternative do I have to be able to go back correctly?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does "doesn't do it correctly" mean?

Comment: I have used two things. On the one hand the label
<ion-back-button>
and on the other the <ion-back-button [defaultHref] = "defaultHref"> tag
with the defaulthref. What happens that when I do not put the defaulthref, history is lost and I can not go back, and in the other way I have to control it, but I see it very archaic. What is the best option for this when you have many screens to go back? Do I have to create a trail so that I have controlled all the screens where I pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `Location from @angular/common` ?

It haves the location.back() method.

Comment: I have used it, but it does not work, it is lost, because with that you know the previous one, but once you go to the previous one, the other one also knows its previous one?

Comment: Have you tried the `pop()` method from Ionic `NavController`? Is native from Ionic and should have all the history tracked.